# C# | Login doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf

I can't figure it out why my Login system doesn't work.

It always resulting "FALSE" or "WRONG PASSWORD" tho I've entered the right password.

And yes, I've checked the column name and the table name as well. Nothing wrong but doesn't work.

I can't figure it out.

```
namespace GitGut {
    public partial class Login : Window {
        public String thisName;
        private String thisConnectionString = @"Data Source = THISISMINE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = GitGut; Integrated Security = True";
        public Login() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Button_Login pressed.");
            if(theValidation(TextBox_Username.Text, PasswordBox_Password.Password) == true) {
                Dashboard Form_Dashboard = new Dashboard();
                Form_Dashboard.Show();
                this.Hide();
            } else {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR", "ERROR");
            }
        }

        private Boolean theValidation(String thisUsername, String thisPassword) {
            SqlConnection thisSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(thisConnectionString);
            SqlCommand thisSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            thisSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = thisUsername;
            thisSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = thisPassword;
            String thisQuery = "SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE [Username] = '@Username' AND [Password] = '@Password'";
            thisSqlCommand.Connection = thisSqlConnection;
            thisSqlCommand.CommandText = thisQuery;
            thisSqlConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader thisSqlDataReader = thisSqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if(thisSqlDataReader.Read()) {
                thisSqlConnection.Close();
                return true;
            } else {
                thisSqlConnection.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `'` from the query string:  `String thisQuery = "SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE [Username] = @Username AND [Password] = @Password";`

Comment: Side note: Always use `using` statements for your instances that implement `IDisposable` like `SqlConnection`. This ensures resources are always released even in the event of an Exception.

Comment: Side note 2: Never store passwords in plain text! Always use a secure 1 way hashing algorithm designed for password storage like PBKDF2, Scrypt, or Bcrypt.

Comment: I'm a noob, I don't even understand that security features.

Comment: If you don't understand security, why are trying to secure something?

Comment: I'm a noob. please understood. wanna try n try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `'` from the query string:

```
String thisQuery = "SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE [Username] = @Username AND [Password] = @Password";
```

The Sqlcommand parameters does not need any separator/indicator. You are already telling what type they are in `thisSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar)...`, so the query string is correctly constructed.

Comment: LOL I was so stupid thanks!